# URLs with symbol "%" at the end make http error, how to prevent it with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a doubt with some of my URLs from  my acces_log . There are some URLs from external sites linking me like http://domain.com/url_name.htm% (yes, with %).

Then... my server returns http error, I need to redirect this fake URLs to the correct way, and I thought in htaccess.

I only need to detect the % symbol in the last character of URL, and redirect without it.
http://domain.com/url_name.htm% --> http://domain.com/url_name.htm

How can I do this?  I was trying with some samples with ? symbol but I didn't have lucky.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried with "RewriteRule ^(.*)\%$ /home" but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Is it possible that... when put the "%" symbol after URL, and server returns me the error400, it doesn't check .htaccess file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the mistake...

It seems that some malformed URLs don't pass to vhost, then these petitions  don't read the .htaccess.

The only way to solve this, is adding in httpd.conf the ErrorDocument 400 directive... Not is the best option for servers with different vhosts.. because all of the will have the same behaviour... but I think that is the only way for this case.

Quotation from [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument):

> Although most error messages can be overriden, there are certain circumstances where the >internal messages are used regardless of the setting of ErrorDocument. In particular, if a >malformed request is detected, normal request processing will be immediately halted and the >internal error message returned. This is necessary to guard against security problems >caused by bad requests.

Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

This page is super helpful about the .htaccess rules.
http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteRule.htm

I saw a few solutions to this that use a small php script too. IE this one replaces #

```
.htaccess
RewriteRule old.php redirect.php?          url=http://example.com/new.php|hash      [R=301,QSA,L]

redirect.php
<?php
$new_url = str_replace("|", "#", $_GET['url']);
header("Location: ".$new_url, 301);
die;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply earlonrails, but this code is only for do a redirect, correct? My main problem is with symbol % and the end of URL, because this symbol is for URL encoding... and my server returns error400.

Only need to change the URL after detect % and the end of URL, any idea?